# Mexican ceviche vs. Japanese sashimi

Tags: sushi, ceviche

Except for the different flavours, how similar is Mexican ceviche to the Japanese sashimi. Do they have the same basis and the same fish types?

Comment: Ceviche is not mexican, has been part in last centuries but it is not native to Mexico.

Comment: Complementing @user24309 's answer, typical mexican ceviche is good but it pales in comparison to Peruvian-style ceviche. The amount of lime juice used in the mexican style drowns a lot of flavours. Peruvian-style ceviche is one of the tastiest dishes I've had in my life!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even with the same fish, sashimi and ceviche are very different dishes:

**Sashimi** is sliced, raw fish that is in its natural state.  Note the glossy, translucent nature of the slices:

[image]

Sashimi is also *just* the fish, although the plate may have additional garnishes.

**Ceviche** is technically uncooked, but has been marinated in citrus juice which coagulates proteins and turns the flesh opaque in a manner similar to cooking.  Ceviche is often combined with onions or other complimentary vegetables.

Note the opaque, white color of the flesh:

[image]

In terms of the fish used, sashimi is often made with oily fish like tuna, yellowtail, or snapper; ceviche is more often made from white fish, or even shrimp or squid.  However, there is considerable variation in both cases.

See also:  [Food Lab article on ceviche](http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/07/the-food-lab-ceviche-and-the-science-of-marin.html)